# Javascript function and submit information

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, smarty

I have a little problem with javascript form submit issue, here is the script

```
function search(val1, val2)
{
    var f=document.search_form;
    $("#val1").val(val1);
    $("#val2").val(val2);
    f.submit();
}
```

and here is the form

```
<form name="search_form" action="val/search/" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" id="search_val1" name="search[val1]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="search_val2" name="search[val2]" value="">
......
    <input name="" type="button" value="Click" onclick="search({$smarty.const.VAL1}, {$smarty.const.VAL2});">
</form>
```

What I know after posting the form is "The form is submitted", I don't know what else is being used and processed after the button click. Could someone tell me something more about this ?

Comment: This question is a bit generic.  Are you asking how forms work or how PHP works to process a form's request?  As a very basic introduction, the `input`, `textareea`, and `select` elements that are inside the `form` element AND have a name attribute will be added the the HTTP request that happens when you "submit" your form.  This request is then processed by your server and passed to the part of your code that handles the action specified in the `action` attribute of the `form` element.  In your case, this is `val/search/`.  To find out more, you'll have to read the manual.

Comment: Thanks, but I know what you say already, i am looking for something beyond that a little more. what is inside Submit and what user defined function in the action (controller) will get and process the request, I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to bind the whole form submit event instead of onclick, that way you don't have to worry about users pressing enter on text field and submitting your form

```
function search(val1, val2)
{
    var f=document.search_form;
    $("#val1").val(val1);
    $("#val2").val(val2);
    f.submit();
}

$('form[name=search_form]').submit(function(e) {
   search("{$smarty.const.VAL1}", "{$smarty.const.VAL2}");
});
```

After the above is run, the browser will invoke a normal submit to `val/search/` since you don't tell it to stop the default event (`via e.preventDefault()`)